# Can I control the power and group on a single-pin flash using a manual trigger?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, wireless-triggers, triggers

So I have:

- YN 560 IV which has both a transmitter and a receiver built in.
- Neewer TT560 Manual flash
- Yongnuo RF 603 II C3 
  I can have the YN on top of my camera and have the Neweer on a light stand with the RF 603 attached to it.

My question is, since the YN 560 IV can control other wireless flashes can it also control and group the Neewer TT560 flash since it's connected to a wireless receiver now?

Comment: What camera are you using?

Answer (score 2):

> ...since the YN 560 IV can control other wireless flashes can it also control and group the [Neewer] TT560 flash since it's connected to a wireless receiver now?

No. It cannot; all you can do is fire the flash in sync.

The RF-603 II C, when used as a receiver cannot do power or group control, so there's no way to communicate that to the flash. An [RF-605](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-rf605-flash-trigger-announced/) transceiver can give group on/off control, but not remote power control.

In addition, the Neewer TT560 (which, like the Amazon Basics flash, I suspect is actually a rebranded [Godox TT560](http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Camera_Flash_TT560.html)) is a single-pin flash without any built-in radio triggering.  Anything attached to its foot can only communicate sync (fire).  No other signals can be received by the flash because it doesn't have the pins to receive them.  Your YN-560IV would behave the same on an RF-603 II; it can only have its group/power controlled via its internal radio transceiver.

If you want remote group/power control, you have to stick with the YN-560III/IV/-660/-560Li models, which also have a compatible built-in transceiver.

Answer (score 0):

When using a third party trigger with a different brand third party flash, the only way to know for sure is to test it or find someone else who has tested it and can confirm that what you want to do works. Even what *should* work in theory sometimes does not in practice when using third party components from different makers.

In your case, we can easily surmise that it will not work because the RF603 is incapable of transmitting any signal other than "fire" and the Neewer TT560 is incapable of receiving any external signal other than "fire".

To do what you want, you need both a radio system that can communicate the additional data *and* a flash that can either receive that data via radio (in a protocol it can understand) or additional pins on the foot of the flash (that match the pins on the hot shoe of the radio receiver attached to it.

Comment: Are there any known flash communication protocols that ride on the sync pin?

Comment: The sync pin carries one bit of data: open or closed to ground. That's it. When closed to ground, the flash provides the energy that travels from the sync pin to the camera's ground and back to the flash to trigger it.

Comment: The risk of having a high trigger voltage flash attached to the camera's hot shoe is enough to discourage any manufacturer from attempting to use that pin for any type of communication protocol. Instead of only frying the flash sync switch (which can happen when high trigger voltage flashes are attached to cameras with low trigger voltage tolerance), it could potentially fry the entire camera.